# React variable change but it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a problem for like 3 hours, and i don't understand why,

The code below should explain my problem:

```
import {useEffect} from 'react'

function shuffle(tab) {
  console.table(tab) //shows initialdata
  var i, j, tmp;
  for (i = tab.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      tmp = tab[i];
      tab[i] = tab[j];
      tab[j] = tmp;
  }
  return tab;
}

function App() {

  useEffect(() => {
    const initaldata = [{a:1}, {a:2}, {a:3}, {a:5}]
    console.table(initaldata) //shows initialdata
    const finaldata = initaldata 
    console.table(shuffle(finaldata)) //shows initialdata shuffled
    console.table(initaldata) //shows initialdata shuffled,  why ?

  }, [])
  return null;
}
```

I tried multiples solutions like isolated "shuffle(initialdata)" in a function.

The fact that the shuffle function update all my variable makes all my code works bad.

Thank you and i hope you will find a solution.
(and sorry if there are some mistakes, im french)

Comment: `shuffle` mutates the original array.

Comment: called by refrence, deep clone the args in shuffle function, `tab = tab.slice()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript passes objects, including arrays, by reference. This means that when you do

```
const finaldata = initaldata
```

both finaldata and initaldata still point to the same array in memory. If you don't want to modify your original data, you'll need to shallow or deep copy your array before modifying it.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript pass them objects by reference, that’s why. If you want to avoid that change the for loop with a map

```
....
const toReturn = tab.map(item =>{
...
});

return toReturn
```

Comment: This doesn't help much because the shuffle algorithm would change. The point of Fisher-Yates is to do in in-place.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to copy the array like this before running shuffle =>

```
const finalData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(initialData));
console.table(initialData);
```

Hopefully this can help
https://dev.to/samanthaming/how-to-deep-clone-an-array-in-javascript-3cig

Comment: This is inefficient. No need to deep clone though, `array.slice()` should do for this.